# Check if Item exists in Grid using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net

I have a grid which allows a user to enter a new Grid item. If the grid item exists or the `tb` is empty it displays the error. Here's the code I came up with.

Can anybody think of a cleaner or more efficient way of doing so?  Thinking about it now, I guess I could have done it all in one function, and placed `InsertTrack()` in the else condition of `DoesTrackExist` and register the script in the `if` statement.

```
 private void InsertTrack()
   {
       if (DoesTrackExist(txtEventTracks.Text))
       {
           using (EMSEntities db = new EMSEntities())
           {
               EventTrack newEventTrack = new EventTrack()
               {
                   TrackName = txtEventTracks.Text
               };                   
                   db.EventTracks.Add(newEventTrack);
                   db.SaveChanges();                   
           }
       }
       else
       {
          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "Error", "alert('Track name cannot be duplicate or empty')", true);
       }
   }
   private bool DoesTrackExist(string txtValue)
   {
       using (EMSEntities db = new EMSEntities())
       {
           var context = from x in db.EventTracks
                         where x.TrackName.Contains(txtEventTracks.Text)
                         select x;

           if (context.Any() || txtEventTracks.Text == "")
           {
               return false;
           }
           else
           {
               return true;
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Malachi, I used your edit, but how can I had that code block when I post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people say that adding private functions which are only called in one place in a class clutter the "private interface" of the class. However I actually do prefer it in some cases. In your case I think it makes sense as it makes `InsertTrack` easier to read so I would not merge the two.

As to `DoesTrackExist`

1. Check `txtEventTracks.Text == ""` first - this avoids performing any query at all.
2. I assume you meant to use the parameter `txtValue` instead of accessing the textbox directly.
3. Might not be more efficient but [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) accepts a predicate as well:

   ```
   private bool DoesTrackExist(string txtValue)
   {
       // maybe even consider IsNullOrWhiteSpace?
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtValue)) 
          return false;
       using (EMSEntities db = new EMSEntities())
       {
           return db.EventTracks.Any(x => x.TrackName.Contains(txtValue))
       }
   }
   ```